# React state does not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I'm trying to change the state when I click the button and only when the state changes run createBattle() but the state does not change after I click the button.

At the beginning I set the state to false. The button is in Form.js with an event onClick={this.handleClick}. Then the event handleClick should set the state to true and when the state changes createBattle() in Battle.js should render the table.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Titles from "./Components/Title";
import Form from "./Components/Form";
import Battle from "./Components/Battle";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component{
  state = {
    startPosition : false
}
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <header>
      <div className="meniu"></div>
      </header>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="main">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="title-container">
                  <Titles />
                  <div className="info">
                     <Form startPosition={this.state.startPosition} />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-container">
                    <Battle startPosition={this.state.startPosition}/>
                </div>
               </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   );
}
};
export default App;
```

Battle.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Square from "./Square";

class Battle extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
        createBattle = () => {
          let table=[];
            for (let i=1; i<=10; i++){
                let children = [];
                for (let j=1; j<=10; j++){
                    children.push(<Square />)
                }
                table.push(<div className="board-row">{children}</div>)
            }
            return table;
        }
    render(){

        console.log(this.props);
        return(
            <div className="center">
                {this.startPosition && this.props.createBattle()}
            </div>

        );
    }
}
export default Battle;
```

Form.js

```
import React from "react";

class Form extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
     }
    handleClick = () =>{
           this.setState({
               startPosition: true
            });
        };
    render(){
        console.log(this.props);
        return(
            <div>
                <button className="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>START</button>
            </div>
        );
    } 
};
export default Form;
```

Comment: Well the state of `Form` is getting updated, but I'm not sure why you think this will have any effect on the state of `Battle`. You're going to need to "lift" this state to a common ancestor and pass the handler down as props, as described well in the React docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 3):

The `state` and `props` of a given component is not shared across other components.

If you need to communicate between components you mostly have 2 different options :

1. Move `state` logic to a common parent and pass this `state` as `props` in child components (Note that you may also need to pass some functions to allow to interact with this parent state from the child components)
2. Use a common state, with a framework like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction) (widely used in complex projects)

Answer (score 0):

React does not support sharing of state or props values.
So you should use any of the following

1. React Redux
2. AsyncStorage